# In Level 5-3, where do I use the final red key?

Tags: steven-universe-attack-the-light

I have an extra red key and have scoured the entire level for a red lock barrier, but cannot find it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is there because you need to be able to open all the gates to 100% the level; therefore, each gate has to have a key behind it so the other gates can open. If one chamber had been empty instead, it would have left you out of luck on the level if you opened that door first (or at any time other than last).

Comment: Thanks!  I asked this question because my game was locked at 99% and this level had not been marked 100% completed, but I couldn't figure out what to do (so I assumed the extra key was related.)  After a game update, the level and the overall completed went to 100%, so I'm left to assume this "99%" thing was a bug that was fixed.